# Copy rows into same table, but change value of one field

Tags: t-sql

I have a list of values:

```
(56957,85697,56325,45698,21367,56397,14758,39656)
```

and a 'template' row in a table.

I want to do this:

```
for value in valuelist:
{
insert into table1 (field1, field2, field3, field4)
select value1, value2, value3, (value)
from table1
where ID = (ID of template row)
}
```

I know how I would do this in code, like c# for instance, but I'm not sure how to 'loop' this while passing in a new value to the insert statement. (i know that code makes no sense, just trying to convey what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop here, SQL is a set based language and you apply your operations to entire sets of data all at once as opposed to looping through row by row.

`insert` statements can come from either an explicit list of values or from the result of a regular `select` statement, for example:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
select col3
      ,col4
from table2;
```

There is nothing stopping you `select`ing your data from the same place you are `insert`ing to, which will duplicate all your data:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
select col1
      ,col2
from table1;
```

If you want to edit one of these column values - say by incrementing the value currently held, you simply apply this logic to your `select` statement and make sure the resultant dataset matches your target table in number of columns and data types:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
select col1
      ,col2+1 as col2
from table1;
```

Optionally, if you only want to do this for a subset of those values, just add a standard `where` clause:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
select col1
      ,col2+1 as col2
from table1
where col1 = <your value>;
```

---

Now if this isn't enough for you to work it out by yourself, you can `join` your dataset to you values list to get a version of the data to be `insert`ed for each value in that list.  Because you want each row to join to each value, you can use a `cross join`:

```
declare @v table(value int);
insert into @v values(56957),(85697),(56325),(45698),(21367),(56397),(14758),(39656);

insert into table1(col1, col2, value)
select t.col1
      ,t.col2
      ,v.value
from table1 as t
    cross join @v as v
```